# calculating without using BigInt

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, biginteger

is there any way to print the value of n^1000 without using BigInt? have been thinking on the lines of using some sort of shift logic but haven't been able to come up with something good yet.

Comment: Of course you could, but it would require implementing portions of what BigInteger libraries do anyway. Is there a reason you don't want to use those libraries?

Comment: If you plan to print it in decimal (base _b_), consider using chunks of 10^k (_b_^k).

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this, and I recommend it as an exercise. Beyond that there's little reason to implement this in a language with an existing BigInteger implementation.

In case you're looking for an exercise, it's really helpful to do it in a language that supports BigIntegers out of the box. That way you can gradually replace BigInteger operations with your own until there's nothing left to replace.

BigInteger libraries typically represent values larger than the largest primitive by using an array of the same primitive type, such as byte or int. Here's some Python I wrote that models unsigned bytes (UByte) and lists of unsigned bytes (BigUInt). Any BigUInt with multiple UBytes treats index 0 as the most-significant byte, making it a big-endian representation. Doing the opposite is fine too.

```py
class UByte:
    def __init__(self, n=0):
        n = int(n)
        if (n < 0) or (n >= 255):
            raise ValueError("Expecting integer in range [0,255).")
        self.__n = n

    def value(self):
        return self.__n

class BigUInt:
    def __init__(self, b=[]):
        self.__b = b

    def value(self):
        # treating index 0 as most-significant byte (big endian)                                                                                
        byte_count = len(self.__b)
        if byte_count == 0:
            return 0

        result = 0
        for i in range(byte_count):
            place_value = 8 * (byte_count - i - 1)
            byte_value = self.__b[i].value() << place_value
            result += byte_value
        return result

    def __str__(self):
        # base 10 representation                                                                                                                
        return "%s" % self.value()
```

The code above doesn't quite do what you want. Several parts of `BigUInt#value` depend on Python's built-in BigIntegers, for instance the left-shifting to compute `byte_value` doesn't overflow, even when `place_value` is really large. In lower-level machine code, each value has a fixed number of bits and left shifting without care can result in lost information. Similarly, the `+=` operation to update the `result` would eventually overflow for the same reason in lower-level code, but Python handles that for you.

Notice that `__str__` is implemented by calling `value()`. One way to bypass Python's magic is by reimplementing `__str__`  so it doesn't call `value()`. Figure out how to translate a binary number into a string of base-10 digits. Once that's done, you can implement `value()` in terms of `__str__` simply by calling `return int(self.__str__())`

Here are some sample tests for the code above. They may help as a sanity check while you rework the code.

```py
ten_as_byte = UByte(10)
ten_as_big_uint = BigUInt([UByte(10)])
print "ten as byte ?= ten as ubyte: %s" % (ten_as_byte.value() == ten_as_big_uint.value())

three_hundred = 300
three_hundred_as_big_uint = BigUInt([UByte(0x01), UByte(0x2c)])
print "three hundred ?= three hundred as big uint: %s" % (three_hundred == three_hundred_as_big_uint.value())

two_to_1000th_power = 2**1000
two_to_1000th_power_as_big_uint = BigUInt([UByte(0x01)] + [UByte() for x in range(125)])
print "2^1000 ?= 2^1000 as big uint: %s" % (two_to_1000th_power == two_to_1000th_power_as_big_uint.value())
```

**EDIT**: For a better low-level description of what's required, refer to chapter 2 of the [From NAND to Tetris](http://www.nand2tetris.org/chapters/chapter%2002.pdf) curriculum. The project in that chapter is to implement a 16-bit ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit). If you then extend the ALU to output an overflow bit, an arbitrary number of these ALUs can be chained together to handle fundamental computations over arbitrarily large input numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Raising a small number - one that fits into a normal integer variable - to a high power is one of the easiest big integer operations to implement, and it is often used as a task to let people discover some big integer math implementation principles.

A good discussion - including lots of different examples in C - is in the topic [Sum of digits in a^b](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70125/sum-of-digits-in-ab) over on Code Review. [My contribution there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70125/sum-of-digits-in-ab/70197#70197) shows how to do fast exponentiation via repeated squaring, using a `std::vector<uint32_t>` as a sort of 'fake' big integer. But there are even simpler solutions in that topic, just take your pick.

An easy way of testing C/C++ big integer code without having to go hunt for a big integer library is to compile the code as managed C++ in Visual C++ (Express), which gives you access to the .NET BigInteger class:

```cpp
#using "System.Numerics.dll"
using System::Numerics::BigInteger;

BigInteger n = BigInteger::Parse("123456789");

System::Console::WriteLine(n.Pow(1000));
```